# C# Deserialize JSON Schema.org Recipe from web

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net, system.text.json

I'm trying to write a recipe parser in C#. I have tried using both Newtonsoft and System.Text.Json. I have used online json class builders and VS2019 Paste as json classes. I have got the Newtonsoft example code to run.

Schema.org Recipe https://schema.org/Recipe

Class I am using. I'm really only interested in these 2 values

```
public class Recipe
{
public string recipeIngredient { get; set; }
public string recipeInstructions { get; set; }
}
```

Code - this code runs with with no error.

```
var document = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\recipeExample.json");
Recipe recipe = null;
try
{
    recipe = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Recipe>(document);
}
    catch (System.Text.Json.JsonException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error parsing : {ex}");
}
```

Trying to read value. No error or value.

```
Console.WriteLine(recipe.recipeIngredient);
```

I'm not sure I understand how a schema.org document needs to be traversed. In the generated classes I can see Graph and Context which I'm guessing are root nodes. But my experiments suggest that I don't need all of the classes - just recipeIngredient and recipeInstructions.
And this is only one recipe - I want to parse a list of recipes and I'm sure they'll all have their own classes so I'm looking for the most generalised way to get the 2 field values I'm seeking.

**EDIT**

Using tymtam's Json Document example I can see that there's an object there with

```
Console.WriteLine(recipes.Count);
```

But I can't get the values to display using

```
Console.WriteLine(recipes[0].Ingredients.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(recipes[0].Instructions.ToString());
```

I also tried to print ingredients with

```
foreach (var recipe in recipes)
{
Console.WriteLine(recipes[0].Ingredients);
}
```

But that only prints the object name and not the elements

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator
```

**EDIT 2: SOLVED**

```
foreach (var ingredient in recipes[0].Ingredients)
   Console.WriteLine(ingredient);

foreach (var instruction in recipes[0].Instructions)
   Console.WriteLine(instruction);
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the json file?

Comment: One possibility is that the recipe is wrapped with an extra object. `{ "Recipe" : {...`.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comment - here is the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wS-CnbPjyi6N77WB0TxEVrUsTQypR2q3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant parts of json are the following:

```
{
   "@context":"https://schema.org",
   "@graph":[
      (...)
      {
         "@type":"Recipe",
         "recipeIngredient":[
            "12 oz rice noodles",
            (...)
         ],
         "recipeInstructions":[
            {
               "@type":"HowToStep",
               "text":"Bring ...",
               "name":"Bring ...",
               "url":"https://..."
            },
            (...)
         ],
  (...)
```

## System.Text.Json with JsonDocument

```
using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json))
{
    JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;
    JsonElement graph = root.GetProperty("@graph");

    var recipes = graph.EnumerateArray()
    .Where(g => g.GetProperty("@type").GetString() == "Recipe")
    .Select(r => new
    {
        Ingredients = r.GetProperty("recipeIngredient").EnumerateArray().Select(p => p.GetString()),
        Instructions = r.GetProperty("recipeInstructions").EnumerateArray().Select(p => new
        {
            @type = p.GetProperty("@type").GetString(),
            text = p.GetProperty("text").GetString(),
            name = p.GetProperty("name").GetString(),
            url = p.GetProperty("url").GetString(),
        })
    })
    .ToList();
}
```

## System.Text.Json with classes

```
class Root 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("@context")]
    public string Context {get; set;}
    
    [JsonPropertyName("@graph")]
    public List<Element> Graph {get; set;}
}


class Element {
    [JsonPropertyName("@type")]
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public List<string> RecipeIngredient {get; set;}

    public List<Instruction> RecipeInstructions {get; set;}
}

class Instruction {
    public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
};
var x = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json, options);
var recipes = x.Graph.Where( o => o.Type == "Recipe");
```

## Json.Net

Please see the official [Querying JSON with LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) or [Querying JSON with SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm).

Here is a mix and match solution with querying and classes:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken t = o.SelectToken("$.@graph[?(@.@type == 'Recipe')]");
var recipe = t.ToObject<Recipe>();

(...)
class Recipe {
    public List<string> RecipeIngredient {get; set;}

    public List<Instruction> RecipeInstructions {get; set;}
}

class Instruction {
    public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

For multiple recipes use SelectToken**s**.

Comment: Thanks @tymtam Can you tell me how to enumerate the lists? I have run the first two examples without error but can't work out what/how to print the list to console.

Comment: You can just serialise it back: `Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(recipes, new JsonSerializerOptions {WriteIndented = true}));`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're reading the entire file at once. so the deserialize method may not be able to assign the individual values because your trying to parse one variable from all the text

if you're using System.Text.Json
you should be able to set 2 properties in your class,

```
public string recipeIngredient {get; set;}
public string recipeInstructions {get; set;}
public override string ToString() => JsonSerializer.Serialize<Recipe>(this);
```

and then when you deserialize you can do something like this

```
public list<Recipe> getRecipe()
{
   using (var jsonFileReader = File.OpenText(filename))
   {
      return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Recipe>(jsonFileReader.ReadToEnd());
   }
}
```

with this you should be able to make a list with the type being your recipe class. and then you should be able to reference the list.
(edit)
I forgot to mention it but you would probably want to call it, to do that you would say
`list<Recipe> recipeList = getRecipe();`
and then you would just iterate through the list and each object would have a ".recipeIngredient" and ".recipeInstructions" that you could use to format the output

Comment: Thank you for answering but I don't understand what you are suggesting. I copied your code List<Recipe> should be uppercase L? Then got the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.Recipe' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.Recipe>

Comment: I would suggest making a new class that isn't tied to a form and having the be your Recipe class with the two fields. your problem seems to be that the Recipe class is referencing a form.

Comment: " a new class that isn't tied to a form" - it is a WinForms app. I created a new Recipe class within the App. Is that what you meant? Not sure where I should put the list<Recipe> getRecipe() - I'm still getting the same error on both the form and in the class. I also added getRecipe(string filename)

Comment: The reason it said
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.Recipe'"
i'm assuming is because the override method uses "this" when its telling the method what its serializing. but in your case the instance of "this" that its addressing seems to be referring to a form. maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to do

Comment: and would you mind linking the content of the json file? I can try writing the code here to see what the problem is

Comment: No worries thank you for your suggestions

Comment: Thanks https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wS-CnbPjyi6N77WB0TxEVrUsTQypR2q3/view?usp=sharing